# Error 91 when creating VBA charts with For loop in a separate worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

My code works as intended when I output iterated charts into the same sheet as the source data (ws491), but I'm getting an error when I try to put them in another sheet (ws491g).

Debug doesn't like this line

`.SetSourceData Source:=Union(ws491.Columns((5 * i) - 8), ws491.Columns((5 * i) - 5), ws491.Columns((5 * i) - 4))`

only when I output to a sheet other than ws491. I know Union can't combine ranges in multiple sheets, but I think I should be able to reference combined ranges from another sheet, right? Any advice is appreciated.

Full code:

```
Set ws491 = Worksheets("49")
Set ws491g = Worksheets("49 Graphs")
Set copyrange = Worksheets("Log Data").Range("A1:A10000,D1:D10000,F1:F10000,I1:I10000,J1:J10000")
Set pasterange = Worksheets("49").Range("B1:AZ1000")
Dim CtNum As Integer

CtNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws491.Range("A2:A100"))

pasterange.ClearContents

For i = 2 To CtNum

wslog.Range("A1:K1" & Lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=ws491.Range("A1")
wslog.Range("A1:K1" & Lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=ws491.Range("A" & i)
copyrange.Copy
pasterange.Cells(1, (5 * i) - 9).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ws491g.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter, (i * 360) - 720, 0, 360, 200).Select

With ActiveChart
    .SetSourceData Source:=Union(ws491.Columns((5 * i) - 8), ws491.Columns((5 * i) - 5), ws491.Columns((5 * i) - 4))
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = Cells(2, (5 * i) - 7)
    .ApplyChartTemplate ( _
        "C:\Users\-------")
    .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = WorksheetFunction.Min(Columns((5 * i) - 8))
    .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns((5 * i) - 8))
End With

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will only work if worksheet `ws491g` is active.

Change it to use a Variable to reference the created chart, like this

```
Dim chrt As Chart
'...

Set chrt = ws491g.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter, (i * 360) - 720, 0, 360, 200).Chart

With chrt
    '...
```